# how to download file from link contain image?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a link contain, such as:

```
<a id="clickLink" href="http://data.sinhvienit.net/2012/T12/img/SinhVienIT.Net---1302911-9xnacom29112012-11.jpg">download</a>
```

I want to download this file when click link, not open new tab and display image. How to do it?

Comment: you want image as a download file or to show image and download popup for another file?

Comment: I want to download file from above link

Comment: this particular image?? open http://data.sinhvienit.net/2012/T12/img/SinhVienIT.Net---1302911-9xnacom29112012-11.jpg in another browser tab and save image??? please elaborate it little more what you want

Comment: If I click on this link, it'll open new tab and display image. Now, I don't want to open this image. I want to auto download when I click on this link. Just download file image and not open file

Answer (score 1):

that is going to require a Content-Disposition header to be sent from the server.
Chrome also supports a download attribute on anchors but there currently an equivalent client side solution on the other browsers.